# Firebird database error when running GBAK

Tags: firebird

I am getting an *"internal firebird consistency check (can't continue after bugcheck)"* when trying to run the GBAK commands on the database. Please explain what this means and how I best can solve this problem.

Comment: See http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq226/ As this might have a myriad of reasons and solutions, I don't think this question is suitable for StackOverflow. Consider posting your question, with more details (Firebird log file, full error message, results of running gfix on a copy etc) to the Firebird-support mailinglist. See http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/mailing-lists/ for info on subscribing.

Answer (score 2):

Usually it means that database file is corrupted. In most cases a run of gfix utility would be enough to mend a database:

```
gfix -mend -full -ignore -user SYSDBA -pas masterkey database.gdb
```

Then do backup-restore using gbak.

Comment: I'd strongly advise to do this on a **copy** of the database (or keep a copy of the database for safe keeping). `-mend` will simply throw away invalid pages or records so it can be backed up. See [Gfix: Database Validation and Recovery](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/gfix-dbverify.html). Doing this without careful consideration of the implications might lead to data-loss.